# Blazor wasm pwa failed for integrity check

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I'm testing PWA features by deploy the project to a server.
The website itself works fine, but the service worker failed.

The error message says it failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource which is a CSS file and the resource has been blocked. At that point, the service worker stop working.

I've tried to disable the integrity check which does bypass the process and the service worker went on to the activate phase, but that is not the way the official website recommended.
Also, delete both bin and obj folder to rebuild the solution and publish the project doesn't change anything.

Is there any other way to resolve this issue?